# I want connect ethereum live network, Is this right?

Tags: cpp-ethereum

I write "eth" in the terminal , then run it . Then I write in my django code.

```
web3 = Web3(HTTPProvider('http://localhost:8545'))
web3 = Web3(IPCProvider())

web3.eth.getBalance('0x923eb8ac53073E9Eee5376290c2dF47451828F61')//valid address
```

But it returns 0 . But this address have balance 0.001 . Now what am I doing wrong here? Why is it not connected to the live server ?

Comment: did you get it sorted?

Answer (score 1):

You may first connect to live network with RPC enabled on port 8545 by running the 
`geth --rpc` command in the CLI.

Then you can connect to your node via `Web3(HTTPProvider('http://localhost:8545'))`.